# What is the simplest queue job manager for linux?

Tags: slurm, task-queue, torque

Frequently, I and my team of 6 members submit tasks to a computer. We want that the computer loads the next job after the previous one is done. We all use the same user.
In another computer we used TORQUE. We also used SLURM. But they seems to be a complicated tool to configure. It is designed for multiple clusters. We have only one computer. Is there a simpler alternative? The operative system that we use is Linux (ubuntu)

Comment: I had a similar requirement and went with SLURM in the end. At least it's well documented and supported. And there are some web-based front-ends that aim to simplify, although the actual results are mixed.

Comment: I had the same problem and the easiest solution I found was to use slurm as well... i couldn't find an easier solution. I wrote my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72365506/how-to-change-a-sequence-of-bash-commands-while-running

Answer (score 3):

The `batch` command can be used as a minimally-features scheduling system for single-user single-node cases.

You submit a job through the standard input of `batch`:

```
echo sleep 300 | batch
```

or you can run `batch` and type the commands in the `batch` prompt.

You monitor the queue with

```
atq
```

and inspect jobs with

```
at -c <jobid>
```

The system will start jobs one by one when the CPU load of the machine falls below a certain threshold.

For more information, refer to the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/batch.1p.html). Note that you might have to install the `at` package and start the `atd` daemon.

If that is too minimal for your need, note that the venerable [task-spooler](http://vicerveza.homeunix.net/%7Eviric/soft/ts/) project was revived and offers more feature, although still less than Slurm, and has both a [CPU](https://github.com/justanhduc/task-spooler/tree/cpu-only) and [GPU](https://github.com/justanhduc/task-spooler) version.