# how to change a sequence of bash commands while running?

Tags: python, bash

Let's say I would like to run two python scripts sequentially. My current solution is to write a bash run.sh script which can contain something like:

```
python foo.py
python bar.py
```

Now let's say that after executing ./run.sh command in a terminal and while foo.py is running (bar.py hasn't started yet), I would like to run baz.py (which has been created after the execution of the ./run.sh command) instead of bar.py. The run.sh script would now look like this:

```
python foo.py
python baz.py
```

My question then is: is it possible? To clarify: is there a way to modify a command line sequence on the fly? This sequence doesn't have to be contained in a bash file and may involve some workflow/pipeline management program that I don't know about.
The main goal is to have a dynamic list of process that I could change on the fly.

Comment: Use an if statement!

Comment: @Zorgoth that is not possible in my case, because baz.py may not exist before the execution. Indeed, I am configuring and correcting scripts while other scripts are running

Comment: The bash script can contain the if statement that depends on a file written by the Python script. It's perfectly possible.

Comment: does this requirement come up often? is this supposed to be an automated change or are you doing this manually? how long does it take `foo.py` to complete? will the 'new' script always be named `baz.py` or could the name change over time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my own problem by using slurm. I found out that my problem was similar to this post: [What is the simplest queue job manager for linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70946428/what-is-the-simplest-queue-job-manager-for-linux)

As said in the end of my question, I needed a job manager tool (thus more general than just the execution of simple script as presented in my over-simplified example). I knew slurm but I wanted to see if someone knew something simpler that could be used on a personal computer (something involving bash or another software instead of going through all the struggle I had while installing slurm).

If someone would like to use slurm on their personal laptop (I tested with Ubuntu 20.04), I advise to follow the following blog posts:

- https://signac.io/development/2020/06/26/local-SLURM-environment.html
- https://blog.llandsmeer.com/tech/2020/03/02/slurm-single-instance.html

The hardest part is the slurm.conf creation (https://slurm.schedmd.com/configurator.html). To give a feedback on my own installation journey, I advise:

- to do the installation as root user,
- to set the SlurmUser as root
- to set the SlurmctldHost and NodeName as the name of your computer
- to let the other parameters as default

Thank you to @Zorgoth, @Diego Torres Milano, @ufopilot and @perperam for their propositions.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a python solution for this. With threading you can run things in "parallel". I made a `run.py` file which then can be ran via bash. This is just the principle. You can change the input in the 'run.py' file to something that suites you purpose.

The first thread starts `run1()` which than starts `test1.py` by importing it. While this is happening the second thread "parallel" starts `run2` where you get asked for an input. If the input is 2 `test2.py` starts and if it is 3 `test3.py` starts running in "parallel" with `test1.py` if that has not finished yet.

```py
# test1.py
import time
print("This is test1.py running")
time.sleep(10)
print("This is test1.py finishing")
```

```py
# test2.py
import time
print("This is test2.py running")
time.sleep(10)
print("This is test2.py finishing")
```

```py
# test3.py
import time
print("This is test3.py running")
time.sleep(10)
print("This is test3.py finishing")
```

```py
# run.py
import threading

def run1():
    import test1
    
def run2():
    i = int(input("2 or 3: "))
    if i == 2:
        import test2
    elif i == 3:
        import test3
    else:
        print("jumped over 2 and 3")
        
t1 = threading.Thread(target=run1)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=run2)

t1.start()
t2.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your Python script `foo.py` write the name of the script you want to a file `./.script`, like so:

```
# imports


with open('./.script.py', 'w') as f:
    f.write('python bar.py')

# do stuff

if condition:
    with open('./.script.py', 'w'):
        f.write('python baz.py')
```

Then your script can look like

```
#!/bin/bash
python foo.py
`cat .script`
```

There is no need to modify it on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple.

```
#! /bin/bash

python3 foo.py
second=$(< second)
python3 "${second:-bar.py}"
```

If you write `baz.py` to `second` file (even if you write it from `foo.py`), then `run.sh` executes it instead of `bar.py`

Answer (score 0):

Using dynamic Tasks from db

```
# create sqlite db with your tasks
$ sqlite3 mydb.sql
sqlite> create table tasks (id integer primary key, name text);
sqlite> insert into tasks values (1,"foo.py");
sqlite> insert into tasks values (2,"bar.py");
sqlite> select * from tasks;
1|foo.py
2|bar.py
```

###### run.sh

```
#!/bin/bash


MYDB="./mydb.sql"

execTask(){
   local id=$1
   task=$(sqlite3 $MYDB "select name from tasks where id = $1")
   [ -z "$task" ] && { echo "no task found for id $id" ; return 1; }
   echo "exec task $task"
   python3 $task
}


execTask 1

execTask 2
```

output:

```
$ bash run.sh
exec task foo.py
exec task baz.py
```

Update Tasks table from console or from an other script

```
$ sqlite3 mydb.sql "update tasks set name = 'baz.py' where id = 2"
```